# Offset input value doesn't 'print' in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Interesting problem while doing some VBA;
When code is run it doesn't 'print' the value on the first empty row.
When skipping trough code with f8 it does work. Seems to be in the last command-line.
Code is:

```
Call SlotjeEraf (Unlock/Unhide VBA)
Dim Answer As Variant
  Dim NextCell As Range
With Sheets("Table")
    Set NextCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
    If NextCell.Row > 1 Then NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Answer = InputBox("Medewerkersnaam:")

    NextCell = Answer

    Call SlotjeErop (Lock VBA/Hide Sheet)

End With
End Sub
```

I personally feel the NextCell = Answer line is the problem but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Try `Set NextCell = Answer` And make sure you use `InputBox"String, Type:=8)`, which makes usre the InputBox returns a `Range`. You need to declare answer as `Range` then: `Dim Answer As Range`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, if you add it as an answer, I can mark it true. You were right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### End(xlUp) vs Find

This post is referring to the following part of OP's code:

```
Dim NextCell As Range
Set NextCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
If NextCell.Row > 1 Then NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)
```

**The Disease**

In the line

```
If NextCell.Row > 1 Then NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)     ' Wrong
```

you forgot to use `Set` (`NextCell` is an object). Use this instead:

```
If NextCell.Row > 1 Then Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0) ' Correct?
```

**Why "Correct?" ?**

If `NextCell` is cell `H1`, a possibility is that it is empty and the code will write to it. Next time '`End(xlUp)`' will again return cell `H1` which is not empty now and will write to it ... and again and again... to conclude:

If cell `H1` is empty or not and all other cells are empty, the code will write to cell `H1`, the point being that most often you have headers in the first row and the code will not add data to the following rows.

On the other hand, the code will work if there is data at least in the 2nd row (e.g. headers in the 2nd row).

**A Reminder**

When using `End(xlUp)`, you always have to keep in mind the following:

1. If there is no data in a column or there is data only in the first
   row, it will return the first cell in the column (referred to in `FirstxlUp1`, `FirstxlUp2`, `FirstFind`).
2. It might also return unwanted results when rows are hidden or
   filtered (referred to in `FirstFind` only).

**A Cure**

The following are some solutions to avoid the previous problems. For a better understanding, they have been simplified.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FirstxlUp1()
    Dim NextCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set NextCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
    End With

    If NextCell.Row = 1 Then
        If NextCell.Value <> "" Then Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1)
    Else
        Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1)
    End If

    NextCell.Value = "TestxlUp1"
End Sub

Sub FirstxlUp2()
    Dim NextCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set NextCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
    End With

    If NextCell.Row > 1 Then
        Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1)
    Else
        If NextCell.Value <> "" Then Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1)
    End If

    NextCell.Value = "TestxlUp2"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FirstFind()
    Dim NextCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Try to find a non-empty cell in the column; 'xlFormulas'
        ' includes finding cells with formulas evaluating to "".
        Set NextCell = .Columns("H").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        ' Or:
        'Set nextCell = .Columns("H").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)

        ' Check if a cell was found. If a non-empty cell was not found,
        ' the range evaluates to 'Nothing'.
        If Not NextCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Found the last non-empty (bottom-most) cell in the column.
            Set NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1)
        Else
            ' All cells in the column are empty.
            Set NextCell = .Cells(1, "H")
        End If

    End With
    NextCell.Value = "TestFind"
End Sub
```

**The Real Cure**

In practice you should **always use headers**. Then you can avoid all this 'If-ing' and use the following one-liners to find the 'first' empty cell in a column like this:

```
Set NextCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
' or:
Set NextCell = Columns("H").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Offset(1)
' Or:
'Set nextCell = Columns("H").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious).Offset(1)
```

**If you're hiding or filtering rows, exclusively use the Find Method.**

Answer (score 1):

All `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` and `Columns` objects need to be clearly specified in which worksheet they are. Like

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
```

otherwise it might be that Excel is picking the wrong sheet to write at.

Or if you want to use the `With Sheets("Table")` statment (which is not used at all right now) then your `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows` and `Columns` statement need to start with a dot:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
    Set NextCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp)
    If NextCell.Row > 1 Then NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Answer = InputBox("Medewerkersnaam:")

    NextCell = Answer

    Call SlotjeErop '(Lock VBA/Hide Sheet)
End With
```